# What is the best approach to binding jQuery events to elements

Tags: jquery, dom, events, dom-events

I am currently working on a site that has thousands upon thousands of lines of jQuery code, there are a lot of click events especially and I was wondering is there a more performance-aware, best practice out there for binding click events or any event to an item.

Surely having 30+ click events on various links and items cannot be good performance wise being registered. The new jQuery 1.7 "on" function is being used, should perhaps the events be bound to the body element or something and then a check will get the item being clicked and then work from there? Or is it a non-issue and binding a lot of events not really an issue for a modern browser or performance?

Comment: Event delegation, obviously. You want to have your static container elements, and predominantly bind handlers to those elements... For instance, if you have a toolbar with buttons, you want one click handler on the toolbar itself.

Comment: How unique is each event on click?

Comment: Well it varies. Some of the click events are for carousels, some are for showing popup modals, some are for passing on events to other elements. So I would say each event is fairly unique.

Comment: Is event delegation an expensive thing? Anyone have a link to a benchmark or anything like that?

Comment: @Dwayne Event delegation is of course less expensive than binding handlers to individual elements.

Comment: PS. I am fixing up code from another developer and usually adopt the approach Adam specified in his answer, was just wondering if there was a more efficient way for binding events on unique elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should bind the elements to the lowest dom element that contains all of the clicked elements.

So if there's a div called `foo` that contains every single element, you'd say:

```
$("#foo").on("click", "yourselector", function(){
});
```

If the your elements are spread across every inch of your page, then you'd listen at the very top:

```
$(document).on("click", "yourselector", function(){
});
```

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I really really hope the previous developer didn't do something like:

```
$("#someButtonId").on("click", function(){
    //this defeats the whole purpose of on!!!
});
```

Comment: This is always how I thought you should do it. Seems to be a subjective thing though, definitely helpful. I didn't write most of the code, so I am wanting to fix it up and make it more efficient. Looks like binding click events to the container of all elements you want to bind on is the best approach.

Comment: Sadly Adam, the previous developer did bind clicks using on single elements like you mentioned that's why I am painstakingly fixing it up, it's a performance nightmare and not to mention it's a Magento site which does some pretty un-PC things to your markup with inline event calls and whatnot.

Comment: I was thinking of using $(document).on("click", "yourselector", function(){ for the code due to the uniqueness of items but wasn't sure if that would be bad performance wise for a page made up of quite a lot of elements.

Comment: @Dwayne - if there's no lower div that contains all of the buttons, then yeah, use `$(document).on` - that's really you're only option

Comment: Thanks Adam, I might do just that. It makes sense binding to document then it does binding to many individual items. I'm sure there is a performance saving there doing it massively once as opposed to many times over and over again.

Comment: @Dwayne Almost all developers will have some sort of content wrapper div, so you should be able to make it at least a little more efficient by binding to a wrapper that excludes header, footer, and potentially sidebar. Adam, there are valid use cases for the last case of `.on()` so I don't think it defeats the purpose at all. For this specific question, it seems like it wouldn't be right (30 individual clicks being bound separately? Yikes!!!) but there ARE use cases.

Comment: @GregPettit - ok, fair enough.  If you do need to attach an event to one specific button I guess saying <that> is no worse (maybe even a smidge better than)  `$("#btn").click(...` - I guess I was a tad shocked at what OP was seeing

Comment: Me, too. Good implied point about .click() too, though; when binding a self-listener it doesn't really make a difference; I just meant that there are times binding a self-listener is fine. AFAIK `.click()` is an alias for `.on()` with the syntax you provided, so beyond 'translating' the alias there's no performance benefit for one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the same event more than once on an element, but if you are having as much as 30 click events on the same link, you should do it differently. Put the code for all those different actions that you want to do in a single event handler instead of binding every little thing by themselves.